# Am I meant to use Bootstrap for all aspects of my layout?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is just a question about the extent of using bootstrap.

Should I be using it for all the  layout aspects of a website? Or is it ok to do a bit of the layout stuff myself (i.e. using CSS etc to set widths, margins et al).

Specifically, I'm referring to the grid-layout aspect of bootstrap. If I'm using the grid for some regions (or perhaps parent regions), do I *need* to keep using it for the child/sibling elements? When viewing in an iPad or somesuch, will the mix up of both styles be a likely source of problems? Could you name any specific problems that might come up?

Answer (score 2):

I personally prefer to stick to the twitter bootstrap classes for layout when using bootstrap-responsive.

For boostrap.css, I tend to apply boostrap.css first and then another style-sheet to override the twitter bootstrap behaviour.

the `!important` css property may be necessary in some casses to  force the override.

But it's perfectly fine to use a mix of twitter bootstrap and your own css for layouts.

Answer (score 0):

I am successfully bootstrap's using content and span12 for the outermost div (and some other elements) and use my own classes for laying out inner divs, so I suppose you shouldn't have any trouble doing it